# How to customize Echart series label text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, echarts

I need to show custom Series label instead of data array value. here my series data array is

```
data: [820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320],
```

When i enable label :

```
label: {
    show: true,
    position: 'top',
    color: "black",
    fontSize:12,
},
```

It show data array value top of my line chart i need to show custom text instead of this data array values 
**[text1,text2,text3...]**

My source code:

```
option = {
xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
},
yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
},
series: [{
    data: [820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320],
    type: 'line',
    symbolSize: 12,
    label: {
        show: true,
        position: 'top',
        color: "black",
        fontSize:12,
    },
  }]
};
```

Comment: can you please create a jsfiddle for this ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please use the formatter property provided by the label object. You can return any type of string. Please use [echarts link](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-line.label.formatter) to study more:

```
label: {
    show: true,
    position: 'top',
    color: "black",
    fontSize: 12,
    formatter: function(d) {
      return d.name + d.data;
    }
```

```js
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [{
    data: [820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320],
    type: 'line',
    label: {
      show: true,
      position: 'top',
      color: "black",
      fontSize: 12,
      formatter: function(d) {
        return d.name + ' ' + d.data;
      }
    },
  }]
};


myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/4.6.0/echarts.min.js"></script>
```